# Error in inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

I have an interface `BaseModel`

```
public interface BaseModel
{
    String toString();
}
```

and an abstract class `BaseData`

```
public abstract class BaseData
{
    public abstract String toString();
}
```

I want my model classes to override the `toString()` method. For this I tried the following ways, one at a time, but not together:

1. Make all my model classes implement the `interface BaseModel`
2. Make all my model classes implement the `abstract class BaseData`

In the first case I do not get a compilation error if I do not override the `toString()` method in my model class. I guess it it considering the `Object.toString()` method as a valid implementation.

But in my second case, if I do not override the `toString()` method, I get a compilation error:

> The type `Title` must implement the inherited abstract method
>   `BaseData.toString()`

where `Title` is one of my model class that extends `BaseData` but does not override `toString()`.

Why is the discrepancy?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call the toString from your interface, JVM will search for a toString method in your `Title`class and all its extended classess. eg. Keep searching till it reaches the end of the tree = Object class.

```
                       Object.class - found toString
                           |
Interface.class   ---  Title.class - can't find toString
```

In java you can only extend 1 class. So your abstract class extends Object.class and overrides the toString method.
Sincs `Title` extends your abstract class, it cannot extend the Object.class by itself.

```
Object.class
     |
Abstract.class - overrides toString
     |
Title.class - has to override toString as it is abstract
```

Comment: This is an awesome answer! Thanks a lot! And also, awesome formatting!

Answer (score 2):

If you specify a method in an interface, you will need to implement it in any class that inherits from the interface. (However I am unsure about why you do not get a compile error here - *this may be as you said because it is using Object.toString() but don't quote me on it*)

For abstract classes, anything marked abstract must be implemented on classes that inherit from it.

The exception to this rule is if you have abstract class *A* which has a subclass *B* (which is also abstract), and *B* has a subclass *C*. *B* doesn't need to implement the toString method **as long as** *C* implements it.

Comment: Then B need to be abstract too.

Answer (score 1):

Because your inherited class is concrete. In this case it must implement all abstrct methods declared in interface that it implements and abstract classes that it extends.

so, just implement this method in your class or mark it as abstract if you mean that it should be abstract.

Answer (score 1):

In case 1 you define a new interface (with toString()) and then implement it. As you deduced because your objects extend Object and Object defines toString() also, any Object subclass will conform to your interface.

In case 2 you define an abstract class with an abstract toString() method that hides the superclass (Object) method. In this case, your subclasses of BaseData need to define an implementation of the new abstract toString() method.

Answer (score 0):

Every object has `toString()` method so if you implement `BaseModel`, it's already fulfill the interface contract. But the `BaseData` you specifically make the method abstract so every subclass must reimplement it.